# Concatenating to a string

Tags: c

I want to concatenate to a string based on a fulfilled condition

Here is the code I tried:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static void print_info(char *product_name, int type)                 
{
    char tmp_str[512] = {0};
    char tmp_product[17] = {0};

    memcpy(tmp_product, product_name, sizeof(product_name));         

    snprintf(tmp_str, (sizeof(tmp_str) - 1),
         "Product: %s",
         tmp_product);

    if (type  >  10)
        snprintf(tmp_str, (sizeof(tmp_str) - 1),
             "%s, type: %u", tmp_str,
             type);

    printf("product info: %s\n", tmp_str);
}

int main()
{

print_info("productA", 2);
}
```

when I run it, I get product info: Product: productA

But when I try
    print_info("productA", 20);
I wanted to get

product info: Product: productA 20
But I get:
product info: , type: 20

Any ideas ?

Thanks,
KW

Comment: `sizeof()` is not what you want. It is the size of the pointer. you need `strlen()` or better `strcpy()` instead of `memcpy()`

Comment: A string that `snprintf` uses for input cannot be used for output. Using the same string for input and output results in undefined behavior. BTW, you don't need the `- 1` when providing the length, `snprintf` takes care of that.

Comment: also what @user3386109 said.

Comment: Note that `snprintf()` returns the number of characters written (or that would have been written had the buffer been big enough) excluding the null byte. You can use that to offset the start position (and length) of the second `snprintf()` statement. If you've got a modern enough compiler, you should be getting warnings about violating the `restrict` condition on `snprintf()`, but if you `len = snprintf(tmp_str, "…first call…", …);` and you've checked the result against `sizeof(tmp_str)`, then there's no reason you can't use `snprintf(tmp_str + len, sizeof(tmp_str) - len, "…second call", …);`.

Answer (score 1):

1. use strlen() to figure out actual size of a string
2. you can't use sprintf input as output
3. you should check for strlen < allocated spaces (some included in the code below, thanks Jonathan - comment above)

Here is a working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static void print_info(char *product_name, int type) {
    char tmp_str[512] = {0};
    char tmp_product[17] = {0};

    memcpy(tmp_product, product_name, strlen(product_name));         

    int len = snprintf(tmp_str, sizeof(tmp_str), "Product: %s", tmp_product);

    if (type  >  10)
        snprintf(tmp_str + len, sizeof(tmp_str) - len, ", type: %u", type);

    printf("product info: %s\n", tmp_str);
}

int main() {
    print_info("productAaaa", 20);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The reason for the incorrect output is due to the second `snprintf()` statement which is printing to the start of `tmp_str` instead of after where the first `snprintf()` left off. Here is a modified version that prints the correct output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>

 static void print_info(char *product_name, int type)
 {
     char tmp_str[512] = {0};
     char tmp_product[17] = {0};

     memcpy(tmp_product, product_name, strlen(product_name));

     snprintf(tmp_str, (sizeof(tmp_str) - 1),
          "Product: %s",
          tmp_product);

     if (type  >  10)
         snprintf(&tmp_str[strlen("Product: ") + strlen(product_name)]+1,
         (sizeof(tmp_str) - 1 - strlen("Product: ") - strlen(product_name) - 1),
              "%s, type: %u", tmp_str,
              type);

     printf("product info: %s\n", tmp_str);
 }

 int main()
 {
 print_info("productA", 20);
 }
```

Here in the second `snprintf()` statement we are printing to `&tmp_str[strlen("Product: ") + strlen(product_name) + 1` which is the memory address after the first `snprintf()` statement.

**Edit**

Note: The code looks a little clunky and that's intended in order to make it clear of why the incorrect output was introduced. niry's answer addresses other issues of the code and is more succinct.